# Prove $x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}=2\cos(2\theta)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Prove $x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}=2\cos(2\theta)$ and $x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}=2\cos(3\theta)$
knowing that there exist a number $x$ given angle $\theta$ such that $x+\frac{1}{x}=2\cos(\theta)$

Doesn't really know how to start this problem, thought that I would some how need to use the double angle identities

Comment: The number $x$ is necessarily real?

Comment: Have you tried squaring both sides?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\left(x+\frac 1x\right)^2 = x^2+2+\frac 1{x^2} = 4\cos^2\theta \\\implies x^2+\frac{1}{x^2} = 2(2\cos^2\theta-1) = 2\cos2\theta$$

Similarly

$$\left(x+\frac 1x\right)^3 = x^3 + 3\left(x+\frac 1x\right) + \frac{1}{x^3} = x^3+\frac{1}{x^3} + 6\cos\theta = 8\cos^3\theta$$

$$ \implies x^3+\frac{1}{x^3} = 2(4\cos^3\theta-3\cos\theta) = 2\cos3\theta$$

Comment: My sincere congratulations.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you!

Comment: +1 for a beautiful answer!

Comment: Thank you!! @TobyMak

Comment: Nice and elegant (+1)

Comment: Thank you! @trancelocation

Answer (score 3):

$$x=\cos\theta\pm i\sin\theta $$

Taking $+$ sign for integer $n$,

using 
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre's_formula,

$$x^n=\cos n\theta+i\sin n\theta$$

$$1/x^n=?$$

Similarly consider $-$ sign